# c# get facebook's customized name

Tags: c#, facebook

I want to get the name from facebook url
for example,
an url is http://www.facebook.com/GetThisName or https://www.facebook.com/GetThisName

I only want to save this word "GetThisName",
how can I do with c# coding? 
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to integrate facebook to your site and retrieve username OR
Do you just want the 'GetThisName' part from the URL ?

Comment: i need to get the shop's likes count,
i tried to replace "www" into "graph" in the url
but some shops used http ://www.facebook.com/pages/GetThisName
some of shops used https ://www.facebook.com/pages/GetThisName
so i cannot call graph.facebook.com/pages/GetThisName directly...

Answer (score 0):

**If you just want the 'GetThisName' part from the URL :**

Make a System.Uri object from your string, it will have several properties for different parts of the path:

```
string path = "http://www.facebook.com/GetThisName";
Uri uri = new Uri(path);
Console.WriteLine(uri.AbsolutePath);
```

**If you want to integrate facebook to your site and retrieve username**

use JS SDK from here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

and retrieve username like this

```
FB.api('/me', function(me) {
document.getElementById('auth-displayname').innerHTML = me.name;
document.getElementById('Email').innerHTML = me.email;
document.getElementById('profileImg').src = uid;
}
```